# Suppose $f,g$ are polynomials with degree $\leq d$. If there exist $C$ and $c$ such that $|f-g|\leq C|x|^{d+1}$ for any $|x|<c$. Do we have $f=g$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

I guess the answer is yes, and here's my sketch of proof, but I'm not sure my argument is correct or not. (Since I didn't use any information about $c$.)
proof:
Let $f=\sum_{i=0}^{d} a_{i}x^{i}$ and $g=\sum_{i=0}^{d} b_{i}x^{i}$. Suppose that $f\neq g$, i.e., there is some $a_{i}\neq b_{i}$. By assumption, we have
$$C\geq \dfrac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{|x|^{d+1}}\geq\sum_{i=0}^{d}|a_{i}-b_{i}|\dfrac{1}{|x|^{d-i+1}}\geq \dfrac{|a_{i}-b_{i}|}{|x|^{d-i+1}}$$
However, as $x\to 0$, RHS $\to\infty$ and LHS $=C$, which contradicts. Therefore $a_{i}=b_{i}$ for all $i$, and so $f=g$.

Comment: The second inequality is backwards: $\frac{\vert f(x)-g(x)\vert}{\vert x\vert^{d+1}}\le\sum\limits_{i=0}^d\vert a_i-b_i\vert\frac1{\vert x\vert^{d-i+1}}$

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment, the step $\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{|x|^{d+1}}\ge \sum_{i=0}^d |a_i-b_i|\frac{1}{|x|^{d-i+1}}$ is problematic. Here is an alternative approach. Let $x=0$ and conclude $a_0=b_0$. Now divides $x$ on both sides of the inequality, we have $|\frac{f-g}{x}|\le C|x|^{d}$ holds everywhere over $|x|< c$ except possibly at $x=0$, thus by continuity, it also holds at $x=0$. Now apply the induction hypothesis to conclude $f-g=0$.

Intuitively, as $Cx^d$ vanishes at $x=0$ of order $d$, the order of vanishing of $f-g$ at $x=0$ is at least $d+1$, but it's a polynomial of degree at most $d$, hence must be the zero polynomial. So it really has nothing to do with the specific value of $c$. This can be made more precise with the help of [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma).

Comment: How did you get $a_0=b_0$?

Comment: When $x=0$, $|(f-g)(0)|=|a_0-b_0|\le C|0|^d$.

Comment: Thanks! It's nice and clear.

Answer (score 2):

The second inequality is backwards; that is, the triangle inequality gives
$$
\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{|x|^{d+1}}\le\sum_{i=0}^d|a_i-b_i|\frac1{|x|^{d-i+1}}\tag1
$$
To fix this, let $a_k\ne b_k$ but $a_i=b_i$ for all $i\lt k$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
C
&\ge\limsup_{x\to0}\frac1{|x|^{d-k+1}}\left|\frac{f(x)-g(x)}{x^k}\right|\tag{2a}\\
&\ge\limsup_{x\to0}\frac1{|x|^{d-k+1}}\left(\vphantom{\sum^d}\right.\overbrace{|a_k-b_k|\vphantom{\sum^d}}^{\gt0}-\overbrace{\sum_{i=k+1}^d\left|(a_i-b_i)x^{i-k}\right|}^{\to0}\left.\vphantom{\sum^d}\right)\tag{2b}\\[15pt]
&=\infty\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your help!